# How to work around the hibernate search (lucene) criteria restriction plus getResultSize issue?

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Hibernate search (lucene) has an issue: If you apply a criteria restriction to `FullTextQuery` and apply pagination restrictions, i.e. `criteria.setMaxResults()` and `criteria.setFirstResult()`, the `fullTextQuery.getResultSize()` returns a count which doesn't include the criteria restriction.

[HSEARCH-753](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HSEARCH-753) acknoweldges this issue and resolves it (only so far as a warning exception is thrown)

Could anyone offer suggestions on how I may work around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, all I've needed to do to fix this is to re-order the code so that the call to `fullTextQuery.getResultSize()` is before the call to `fullTextQuery.list();`

Which I hesitate to even mention since it feels a little too "Voodoo" - but it's certainly working...

Answer (score -2):

I used Hibernate Query for paging purpose it supported. checkh the below code for more details

final Query query = session.createQuery(getSession().getNamedQuery("Your query");

query.setMaxResults(20);
query.setFirstResult(10);

Comment: Thanks but it's a hibernate search (lucene) issue I'm facing. Please check out the above link regarding the exception catching. :-)